# Two PHP arrays, unset positions that are only present in one array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, unset, array-unset

I have two arrays (in PHP):

```
ArrayA
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 7
)

ArrayB
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 8
)
```

I want to make two new arrays, where I have only the elements declared in both of the arrays, like the following:

```
ArrayA
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 7
)

ArrayB
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 8
)
```

In this example ArrayA[2] doesn't exist, so ArrayB[2] has been unset.

I wrote this for loop:

```
for ($i = 0, $i = 99999, $i++){
    if (isset($ArrayA[$i]) AND isset($ArrayB[$i]) == FALSE)
    {
        unset($ArrayA[$i],$ArrayB[$i]);
    } 
}
```

But it's not great because it tries every index between 0 and a very big number (99999 in this  case). How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [array_intersect_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

> array_intersect_key() returns an array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments.

Since you want both arrays, you'll have to run it twice, with the parameters in opposite orders, as it only keeps keys from the first array.  An example:

```
$arrayA_filtered = array_intersect_key($arrayA, $arrayB);
$arrayB_filtered = array_intersect_key($arrayB, $arrayA);
```

Also, although a for loop wasn't ideal in this case, in other cases where you find yourself needing to loop through sparse array (one where not every number is set), you can use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arrayA as $k=>$a)
    if (!isset($arrayB[$k]))
        unset($arrayA[$k];
```

Comment: You can use array_intersect too, if you want what is common in both.

Answer (score 1):

One very important thing to note about PHP arrays is that they are associative. You can't simply use a for loop, as the indices are not necessarily a range of integers. Consider what would happen if you applied this algorithm twice! You'd get out of bounds errors as `$arrayA[2]` and `$arrayB[2]` no longer exist!

I would iterate through the arrays using nested `foreach` statements. I.e.

```
$outputA = array();
$outputB = array();
foreach ($arrayA as $keyA => $itemA) {
    foreach ($arrayB as $keyB => $itemB) {
        if ($keyA == $keyB) {
            $outputA[$keyA] = $itemA;
            $outputB[$keyB] = $itemB;
    }
}
```

This should give you two arrays, `$outputA` and `$outputB`, which look just like `$arrayA` and `$arrayB`, except they only include key=>value pairs if the key was present in both original arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to php : array_diff

http://docs.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-diff.php

Comment: array_diff operates on values, OP is clearly concerned with the keys.

Comment: I just hope that people will read the entire page and find other function related ! But yah, should look array_diff_assoc, or better, array_intersect_assoc.